# How do I use flatten logic in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
select * from
(SELECT ID,purchase_list,
      CASE WHEN purchase_list LIKE '12432%'  THEN replace(purchase_list,12432,'Amt_Saved: Mastercard(12432)')
     END AS purchase_amt    
  FROM (
        SELECT ID,index,d.value::string AS purchase_list 
 FROM (
       SELECT  ID,c.value::string AS purchase_list
      FROM table_1,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(purchase_order_list, '|')) c                
     ), LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(purchase_list, ';')) d
       ) 
 )WHERE purchase_amt is not null
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting results as mentioned below:

```
ID         PURCHASE_LIST         PURCHASE_AMT
12810789    12432=3.00           Savings1: Mastercard(12432)=3.00
12810789    12432=0.99           Savings1: Mastercard(12432)=0.99
12810789    12432=0.49           Savings1: Mastercard(12432)=0.49
```

I want to sum up these amounts (3.00 + 0.99 + 0.49)=4.48 and display this result in same column or another COLUMN

The result should look like:

```
ID         PURCHASE_LIST         PURCHASE_AMT
12810789    12432=4.48            4.48
```

How to implement this using SUM function by using any other logic?

Kindly guide. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your existing SQL can be rewritten to be:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    d.value::string AS purchase_list,
    IFF( purchase_list LIKE '12432%', REPLACE(purchase_list, 12432, 'Amt_Saved: Mastercard(12432)'), null) purchase_amt    
FROM table_1 AS a 
    ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(a.purchase_order_list, '|')) c                
    ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(c.value::string, ';')) d
WHERE purchase_amt IS NOT NULL;
```

So we can add a SUM() OVER() clause to get a total per row, it you are want parts and total:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    d.value::string AS purchase_list,
    IFF( purchase_list LIKE '12432%', REPLACE(purchase_list, 12432, 'Amt_Saved: Mastercard(12432)'), null) purchase_amt,
    SUM(REGEXP_REPLACE(purchase_list, '12432=([0-9.]+)', '\\1', 1,1,'e')::number(9,3)) over (partition by id) as sum_total
FROM table_1 AS a 
    ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(a.purchase_order_list, '|')) c                
    ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(c.value::string, ';')) d
WHERE purchase_amt IS NOT NULL;
```

| ID | PURCHASE_LIST | PURCHASE_AMT | SUM_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12810789 | 12432=3.00 | Amt_Saved: Mastercard(12432)=3.00 | 4.48 |
| 12810789 | 12432=0.99 | Amt_Saved: Mastercard(12432)=0.99 | 4.48 |
| 12810789 | 12432=0.49 | Amt_Saved: Mastercard(12432)=0.49 | 4.48 |

OR you can group and not care about all the sub values:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    SUM(REGEXP_REPLACE(d.value::string, '12432=([0-9.]+)', '\\1', 1,1,'e')::number(9,3)) AS sum_total
FROM table_1 AS a 
    ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(a.purchase_order_list, '|')) c                
    ,LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(c.value::string, ';')) d
GROUP BY 1;
```

gives:

| ID | SUM_TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 12810789 | 4.48 |

Comment: I'm getting these errors- Numeric value is not recognized and Numeric value out of range. Can this be sorted using TRY_CAST or TRY_TO_NUMBER?

Comment: right so when I used `::number(9,3)` I didn't explain what I was doing, so that's my bad, that is defining a fixed point number, that can only hold 9 digits after the decimal place, and three below the decimal place. If you have larger number or more precision needed you will need to use a value that is valid for your data. You could use FLOAT/DOUBLE (they are the same) but floating point numbers are not suitable for handling money. And given you mentioned "credit cards names and numbers" I lent into safe, of easy.