# I need help in forming a SQL query to display the numeric values after equal to symbol

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the below table, I need to display only the numeric values for the PRICE_CHARGED column.

```
TID      LIST_PRICE           PRICE_CHARGED
01254    04768=1.00           Amount: purchase(04768)=1.00
01254    04768=0.55           Amount: purchase(04768)=0.55
01254    04768=9.50           Amount: purchase(04768)=9.50
```

I would want to display only the numeric values after equal to symbol.

The result needs to be like this:

```
 PRICE_CHARGED
    1.00
    0.55
    9.50
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is to funny, you must work with "Jenifer" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71501121/how-do-i-use-flatten-logic-in-snowflake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`split_part`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html) function should help here. It will take a string value, split it by a specified string, and return the 1-based index value.

`select split_part(PRICE_CHARGED, '=', 2) from <my_table>;`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I really  appreciate.